# Evaluate derivative after replacement?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a simple integration by parts on functions with zero boundary conditions. For example, I currently have something like

```
g[x]D[A[x], x]/.{D[A[x], x] n_[x] -> -A[x] D[n[x], x]}
```

This has worked, but I run into an issue when I have more than two functions in a term, i.e. something like `f[x]g[x]D[A[x], x]`. I have tried the following:

```
f[x]g[x]D[A[x], x]/.{D[A[x], x] n_ -> -A[x] D[n, x]}
```

but this predictably returns zero. Can someone help me with the proper way to do this?

Comment: Something like `Derivative[1][A][x] n_ :> -A[x] D[n, x]`? (If so, then the standard hint to figure out pattern-matching is to look at the full form `FullForm[f[x] g[x] D[A[x], x]]`.)

Comment: Thank you that works! I'm not sure I understand though, what is the difference between that and the expression I wrote? (Edit: Nevermind I saw your explanation in the parenthetical)

Comment: The difference is `->` vs `:>`  Try it with your code.  See also the documentation for `RuleDelayed`.